# SUDS fails in GUI, but works in unittest

Tags: python, suds

I have a weird problem with SUDS in python.

I am writing an application, that uses a SOAP service. And for approximately 2 months everything was going fine. All of a sudden, it stopped working. Here is the weird part though.

If I run the unittest for the suds manager I wrote, everything goes well and the test passes like usual. If I run the code in the GUI application it fails, with the following traceback:

```
ERROR:suds.client:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://service.skip.fiskistofa.is/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:getLandings>
         <from>2013-10-11</from>
         <to>2013-10-01</to>
      </ns0:getLandings>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/fintor/bin/python/aflafrettir/gui/gui.py", line 332, in run
    landings = self.manager.get_landings(self.date_from, self.date_to)
  File "/home/fintor/bin/python/aflafrettir/landings/manager.py", line 66, in get_landings
    return self.call_method('getLandings', date_from, date_to)
  File "/home/fintor/bin/python/aflafrettir/landings/manager.py", line 49, in call_method
    return getattr(self.client.service, method)(*args)
  File "/home/fintor/.virtenvs/aflafrettir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/fintor/.virtenvs/aflafrettir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "/home/fintor/.virtenvs/aflafrettir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "/home/fintor/.virtenvs/aflafrettir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 702, in failed
    r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
  File "/home/fintor/.virtenvs/aflafrettir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
    raise WebFault(p, faultroot)
WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'C' (code 67) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]'
```

The code that fails, is running in a thread within the GUI application(PySide), the relevant code is here:

```
class Worker(Thread):
  signal = AflafrettirSignal()

  def __init__(self, queue, manager, date_from, date_to):
    super(Worker, self).__init__()
    self.queue = queue
    self.manager = manager
    self.date_from = date_from
    self.date_to = date_to
    self.daemon = True

  def run(self):
    landings = self.manager.get_landings(self.date_from, self.date_to)

    for l in landings:
      tmp = Landings()
      tmp.set_variable(l)
      tmp.calc_total_catch()
      self.queue.put(tmp)

    self.signal.work_done.emit(True)
```

and it's called in the gui like so:

```
manager = LandingsManager()
manager.set_credentials(self.username, self.password)
manager.get_client()
worker = Worker(self.queue, manager, date_from, date_to)
worker.start()
```

Finally, here is the code from the unittest module, which is working fine:

```
manager = LandingsManager()
manager.set_credentials(usern, passw)
manager.get_client()
data = manager.get_landings('2013-10-01', '2013-10-11')
```

I have verified that the username and password is the same when I set the credentials as well as the date from and date to when I call the get_landings method.

Like I said, it is a weird problem, and I am not sure what causes this to fail in one place, and work in another. I hope that someone can enlighten me regarding the cause.

**EDIT:**

I figured out what was wrong. The password contained a carriage return, and the SOAP service did not like that.

Comment: Can you find out what data is getting POSTed.  That might help find out what is causing the SOAP server to raise an exception.  Wireshark might be helpful here

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. The password from the GUI contained a carriage return, and the SOAP service did not like that. Thanks, @ldrumm for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You might want to add that as an answer and accept it after the specified time interval, just in case somebody else ever has the same issue  :)